# Why isn't this working? It works in Rubular though

Tags: regex

```
text.gsub!(/(?<!http:\/\/)www\.(?=\w)/,'http://www.')
```

is what i have...and it says undefined(?...) sequence. When I use `(?<!http:\/\/)www\.(?=\w)` in rubular it does just what i want, but then this doesn't work for me so I need some help.

This is supposed to replace `www. to http://www.` This is homework for a class so it has to do exactly that.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: Could you post your text string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
text.gsub(/^(?!http:\/\/)www(.*?)$/, 'http://www\1')
```

[Regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/aA6yQ6)

It replaces all instances of `www`, not preceded by `http://`, with `http://www.something.com`

### Regex explanation

```
Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!http://)»
   Match the characters “http://” literally «http://»
Match the characters “www” literally «www»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
```